# Webview loadDataWithBaseURL not displaying html android

Tags: android, android-webview

Trying to render html which is passed from a webservice to display in a webView using the loadData/loadDataWithBaseURL.

I've encoded the html string TextUtils.htmlEncode and wrapped it in <html> <body> but nothing is displayed.

```
mMessageDetailsHtmlString = &lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;color:#ffffff&quot; align=&quot;center&quot;&gt;&lt;h3&gt;Test Promo&lt;/h3&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;color:#ffffff&quot;&gt;Here is some text about a great test promo.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;color:#ffffff&quot;It includes an image (below) using a fully qualified URL&lt;p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;color:#ffffff&quot;&gt;&lt;img href=&quot;http://myserver.com/media/images/img-logo.png&quot; /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;color:#ffffff&quot;&gt;This is a test message with white text&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;

//used loadDataWithBaseURL with a fake base url as loadData didn't work
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://null", mMessageDetailsHtmlString, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks the text in that html is white, is your webview's background white too by any chance?

Try `mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);`

Comment: omg! completely missed the fact my html text was white, Thanks